# Md-ripple in Angular2 Material

Tags: javascript, angular, material-design, angular-material2

I didn't find any information anywhere how to use md-ripple from ng2 material.

Tried

```
<button md-ripple-foreground class="loginButton"></button>
```

or

```
<button md-ripple-fade-in class="loginButton"></button>
```

or

```
<button md-ripple class="loginButton"></button>
```

But none of them actually works. How to turn it on?

If you dont know how ripple works: https://codepen.io/Craigtut/pen/dIfzv

https://github.com/angular/material2/tree/master/src/lib/core/ripple

Comment: Try can just use the md-button directive in your button. It will add the ripples for you

Comment: `<button md-raised-button md-ripple-fade-in type="button" ></button>` Still doesnt work :( @benny_boe

Comment: @H.Doe but the last link you give actually explains how you have to use it.

Comment: @PierreDuc Im following the instructions but somehow it doesnt work...

Answer (score 7):

Was facing the same problem, this is how I went about it - 
I wanted to implement it inside a MdCard and it worked.

In app.module.ts, or wherever your module file is ->

```
import { MdRippleModule } from '@angular/material';
```

Don't forget to declare inside your imports inside @NgModule in the same file

```
imports: [ MdRippleModule ]
```

Now head straight to tag where you want to implement the ripple effect directive

In my example:

```
<md-card
  md-ripple
  mdRippleColor="#00E4AC">
Content 
</md-card>
```

For more properties like mdRippleColor used in the example above, please refer this link: h̶t̶t̶p̶s̶:̶/̶/̶g̶i̶t̶h̶u̶b̶.̶c̶o̶m̶/̶a̶n̶g̶u̶l̶a̶r̶/̶m̶a̶t̶e̶r̶i̶a̶l̶2̶/̶b̶l̶o̶b̶/̶m̶a̶s̶t̶e̶r̶/̶s̶r̶c̶/̶l̶i̶b̶/̶c̶o̶r̶e̶/̶r̶i̶p̶p̶l̶e̶/̶R̶E̶A̶D̶M̶E̶.̶m̶d̶#̶a̶p̶i̶-̶s̶u̶m̶m̶a̶r̶y̶ (Link is no longer available due to version upgrade)

Comment: Please note, this answer is no longer supported if your version is higher than beta.11

Comment: Latest solution for Angular Material 4 and 5: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46468995

Comment: For ng6, just replace 'Md' with 'Mat' and it works like a charm. Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

```
const globalRippleConfig: RippleGlobalOptions = {
  disabled: false,
  baseSpeedFactor: 1.5 // Ripples will animate 50% faster than before.
};
```

and

```
<style>
    .ripple{
      position: relative;
     }
  </style>
 <div class="ripple" md-ripple>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a `[mdRippleColor]` or a `[mdRippleBackgroundColor]` in your element. Otherwise it defaults to the css background colour and you won't see any effect:

```
<button md-ripple class="loginButton" mdRippleColor="#F00"></button>
```

Comment: It's default color grey and I cant do anything about it. `mdRippleColor="#F00"` doesnt work.

Comment: Did you import mdRippleModule in your app module? Worked for me then ... only have to figure out how to get the hover color changed :/