# Angular4 Change md-button's ripple color

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have created a md-button in my webpage using Material for Angular4. Is there a way to change the ripple effect's color and make it white? Can I also change other ripple properties, like the duration of the ripple effect?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368434/angular-material-change-color-of-md-radio-button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular Material - change color of md-radio-button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45368434/angular-material-change-color-of-md-radio-button)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It turned out that in order to change the ripple properties, one should create a mixin at the mat-ripple-theme and import it in their app's styles.scss file:

```
@import '~@angular/material/theming';

@mixin mat-ripple-theme($theme) {
  .mat-ripple-element {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .4);
  }
}
```

Comment: There is a ripple mixin in 
https://github.com/angular/material2/blob/master/src/lib/core/ripple/_ripple.scss

Available when you import `@import '~@angular/material/theming';`